# Importing an image from camera roll and cropping it

Tags: ios, iphone, cocos2d-iphone

I load an image from the camera roll and send it to a function which returns a section of the original image based on a rectangle I create. I can then add this to the scene with no issues.

The problem occurs when I want to load another section of the original image. I want to create 2 sprites, each with different sections of the original image, like a jigsaw, but when I send the original image and a different rectangle, I get the same image as the first time and have two images the same added to the scene.

Any ideas would be appreciated?

```
-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
    // newImage is a UIImage do not try to use a UIImageView
    UIImage *newImage = [info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"];
    UIImage *newImage2 = [info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"];
    //newImage2 = [info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"];
    // Dismiss UIImagePickerController and release it
    [picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    [picker.view removeFromSuperview];
    [picker    release];

    CGRect newRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 460);
    CGRect newRect2 = CGRectMake(600, 600, 100, 100);

    UIImage *testImage = [self imageFromImage:newImage inRect:newRect];
    UIImage *testImage2 = [self imageFromImage:newImage2 inRect:newRect2];

    CCSprite *scaledImage = [CCSprite spriteWithCGImage:testImage.CGImage key:@"ImageFromPicker"];
    scaledImage.position = ccp(s.width/2, s.height/2);
    [self addChild:scaledImage];

    CCSprite *scaledImage2 = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"play.png"];//[CCSprite spriteWithCGImage:testImage2.CGImage key:@"ImageFromPicker"];
    scaledImage2.position = ccp(560,40);
    [self addChild:scaledImage2];
}
```

And the method that crops the image:

```
- (UIImage *)imageFromImage:(UIImage *)image inRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    CGImageRef sourceImageRef = [image CGImage];
    CGImageRef newImageRef = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect(sourceImageRef, rect);
    UIImage *tempImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:newImageRef];
    return tempImage;
}
```

Comment: are you sure the image is > 600x600 points? Alternative: create a CCTexture2D from the UIImage. Then you can create sprites from texture and rect. You don't need to use CG functions for what you want to achieve.

Comment: The original image is a large panoramic image and so the whole image cannot be imported as it is too large, so wanted to load just some sections of it. Can I still do this with a CCTexture2D?

Comment: If you crop it first to at most 4096x4096 or 2048x2048 depending on which devices you are going to support. So do the cropping down to texture size limits with CG and then create a CCTexture2D, that would work.

Comment: Thanks for the info, that seems like the way to go. One more question on this. Say the image is 4096x8000, could I load the first half as a texture, then load the second half as a texture, so I can have access to all of the image or is there an easier way to do this?

Comment: Should be possible if you create two separate textures from the image

Comment: Thanks, I will give it a try. Is there any obvious reason why I cant do the same with the above code? as it just displays the same section of the image in both.

Comment: Can I select you as the best answer, as using two CCTextures worked?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to LearnCocos, you were spot on with your answer. Created 2 separate textures from different part of the larger image and could then add them separately.